# Why does $|x^2| = x^2$, only if $x$ is positive? (according to Wolfram Alpha)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value, wolfram-alpha

I don't understand why Wolfram says $|x^2|$ is equal to $x^2$, but only when $x$ is positive. Since we're squaring the value of $x$, the input to $abs$ will always be positive, and the result will be identical to the input. Here's my proof:

Lets take two possible values of $x$: $k$, and $-k$, and compare their equations: $|k^2|$ and $|(-k)^2|$

It's trivial that $(-k)^2$ = $k^2$, since $(-k)^2$ = $(-1)^2 \cdot k^2$ = $1 \cdot k^2$ = $k^2$.

So $|(-k)^2|$ = $|(-1)^2 \cdot k^2|$ = $|1 \cdot k^2|$ = $|k^2$|.

So it then follows that since $|k^2| = k^2$ when $k$ is positive,  $|k^2| = k^2$ for all values $k$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: No where. We indeed have, for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;|x^2|=x^2\;$ . It doesn't matter whether $\;x\;$ is positive or negative or zero. WA gets high, and sometimes really high, in several elementary things. Don't trust it blindly.

Comment: Alpha probably isn't considering the whole problem, but looking just at $abs(A)=A$ which is true for $A\geq 0$.  Or something like that...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Wolfram Alpha page you're looking at?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang possibly [Alternate form assuming x is positive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%5E2%7C)

Comment: I asked Wolfram Alpha [When does |x^2| = x^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=when+does+|x^2|+%3D+x^2) and it correctly replied $$ \text{Im}(x)=0$$ and  "Solution over the reals: (all values of $x$ are solutions)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we're looking at the [page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%5E2%7C) linked by The Chaz 2.0:

[image: wolfram alpha page]]

I read this as telling the truth but not the whole truth.  In other words, *if* $x$ is positive *then* $|x^2| = x^2$.  Wolfram Alpha is not saying that if $x^2 = |x^2|$ then $x$ is positive.  That would be false, as you point out.

I am not sure why Wolfram Alpha provides this incomplete information.  It does try to be general and not assume that variables have strictly *real* values.  Notice that $|i^2| \neq i^2$.  As for why it doesn't say “Alternate form assuming $x$ is real,” who knows.

Comment: Yes this is the page, thank you.